# Creating permanent SSH tunnels in PHP

Tags: php, ssh-tunnel

I have a function that needs to return a PDO object to a remote host via an SSH tunnel in PHP.

I currently have it working in such a way that when the PDO object is requested, it creates the SSH tunnel, connects PDO and returns the PDO object.

I would like to be able to create the SSH tunnel once and have it stay there, so that when I have 100 requests for a PDO object to a specific remote server, I only create the SSH tunnel once.

At the moment, the SSH tunnel is destroyed when the script finishes running.

How can I set it up to achieve this?

Currently I have tried:

```
exec('ssh -fNg -L 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@host > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

and

```
exec('autossh -f -M 13308 -fNg -L 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@host > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

In both cases the tunnel is destroyed when the script exits.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you literally tunnelling to localhost? Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: So you want the tunnel to stay open after the script exits. Why are you opening the tunnel in the script and not in something that can be managed separately? For example: a shell script that you run independently of the web server

Comment: @Joni - The simplified version is that a user can click "connect to remote server" and enter a server name in the web page. Once connected, there will be many future requests to the same server. Before connection, the system does not know that it will be going to connect, hence I want the tunnel to be initiated by the user, but remain connected thereafter. I am opening the tunnel in the script, because I am not sure how else to achieve this.

Comment: @Sammitch - I am not tunneling to localhost , I am tunneling to user@host

Answer (score 2):

That is an odd use case, and not something that I would particularly recommend to be accomplished via forking off of web requests. [or at all, really] However you might be able to leverage ssh's `ControlMaster` to handle persisting and multiplexing connections on its own.

Add the following options:

1. `-o ControlMaster auto`

   - Enables the sharing of multiple sessions over a single network connection.
2. `-o ControlPersist 30`

   - Specifies that the master connection should remain open in the background after the initial client connection has been closed.
3. `-o ControlPath /path/to/socket/dir/%r@%h-%p` [optional, but recommended]

   - Specify the path to the control socket used for connection sharing.

Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

It's important to note that once the ControlMaster socket has been established any user that is permitted to access it can do so without authentication. You may want to segregate the socket paths from each other based on application authentication/authorization.

With the above the ssh binary itself handles what is essentially the dameonization necessary to persist the connection, wait for the timeout to expire, and gracefully close the connections. Though one thing to note is that if the ssh process is killed the sockets still exist and will need to be cleaned up manually before connecting again.

Also, this code relies on an IMMENSE level of trust in your users to not do anything stupid and/or malicious. At a minimum make sure you're making liberal use of [`escapeshellarg()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [`escapeshellcmd()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) on *any and all* user input that might make its way into an executed command.

Comment: Interesting, thankyou. I want to make sure I fully understand the security implications here. The ssh tunnel has the -N option so users can't run commands, and the user's shell is set to /bin/true. It only forwards to port 3306 (MySQL), so they would need a valid login to do anything anyway. Besides all of that, users aren't exposed to any free input other than typing the domain initially to create a connection to. They just see a list of documents for that server (gathered via SQL over the tunnel). But there might be 10 req/sec, 8hrs/day hence wanting one, persistant tunnel.

Comment: Also to add to this, my plan is to start (and keep-alive) the tunnels on boot (with a different port per server), so this only happens the first time a connection is made to a specific server, I just don't know if it's possible to kickstart it from PHP the first time.

Comment: `-N` doesn't imply "can't", but only "doesn't", and I have my doubts that it applies to the socket, rather just that particular invocation of the `ssh` command. Assume that: 1. Any user that manages to access the socket will essentially have a pre-authenticated SSH session. 2. Your users are always malicious. That said, unattended SSH tunnels are like this are a kludge around setting up a proper VPN, IMHO.

Comment: Most of the time the connections are over a private network, but there are use cases for external servers where my only access method is SSH, and that's what I am trying to nail down. My idea was to have an SSH tunnel to the host then PHP can access MySQL as if it were localhost. It seems like a good solution, but I am worried about running into perfomance issues if it gets created and destroyed 100 times in a second at peak. (Plus I'm not sure how to efficiently manage ports so they are all isolated).